# Open activity_xx.xml upon activity creation

Tags: android, android-studio

Upon creation of a new activity in Android Studio the java class and the content_xx.xml file opens automatically for editing.

Is there a way to automatically open the activity_xx.xml file for editing alongside the content xml and java class?

Comment: Why can't you just open it? Is it really hard? Using commands like Double Shift, then type activity_xx.xml should easily open the file for you

Comment: To clarify: would like them opened side by side?

Comment: @Eenvincible That's not really helpful. Of course I have the ability to open it. When sorting through a long list of other activities and creating several others in consecutive order, it's time wasted to scroll through the list.

Comment: @MarcinKoziński side by side would be fine. The window arrangement is not important. Would just like it to open in the tabs at the top upon creation